# How to programmatically download a CSV using Windows Service into my website

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, csv

How to programmatically download a CSV using **Windows Service** into my website?

Reference to any articles or tutorials would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FileWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest.aspx) in your service.

There is an example in the linked page.